# How can I get Image similarity in percentage from Homography matrix?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm using [Emgu.CV](https://github.com/artemisvision/emgu_openCV) .net Wrapper for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) to accomplish this. I got the following data from `FindMatch` Method.

```
FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, matches,
               out mask, out homography);
```

How can I calculate similarity from `mask`,`matches` or `homography`?

I want to identify the images of the same object taken. (Photo will be taken in same angle and orientation)

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/FAST_feature_detector_in_CSharp?

Comment: @balaji but how can i know how similar the images are?

Comment: You need to extract feature vectors (FAST, LBP, SURF, whatever in your case) for both your template and test images. Then directly measure the similarities between these two vectors. One instant solution would be Euclidean distance. Your method varies depending on your actual need. Please be specific if more information is needed.

Comment: @derman This findmatch method uses surf to find similarity. However, this method returns array of low and min distance from these points. But dont know how to calculate probability from these distances.

Comment: @derman How can we find similarity from the generated homography matrix.